# BERT Vocabulary : Why every word has '▁' before?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, french

my question is related to camemBERT model (french version of BERT) and its Tokenizer :

Why every word of the vocabulary has a "▁" character before ?
For example, it's not "sirop" but "▁sirop" (sirop => syrup).

```
from transformers import CamembertTokenizer
tokenizer = Camembert.Tokenizer.from_pretrained("camembert-base")
voc = tokenizer.get_vocab() #Vocabulary of the model

print("sirop" in voc) # Will display False
print("▁sirop" in voc) # Will display True
```

Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly the CamembertTokenizer uses this special character from SentencePiece, see the [source code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/camembert/tokenization_camembert.py#L42).

SentencePiece on the other hand uses Subword Tokens (splitting of words into smaller tokens), but to internally always keep track of what is a "real" split between words (where there was a whitespace) and what is a Subword splitting, they use this character before the start of each "real" token, follow-up subword tokens (but not punctuation) don't have this token, see the [Explaination in the Github Repository](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece#whitespace-is-treated-as-a-basic-symbol). Basically the whitespace is always part of the tokenization, but to avoid problems it is internally escaped as "▁".

They use this example: `"Hello World."` becomes `[Hello] [▁Wor] [ld] [.]`, which can then be used by the model and later transformed back into the original string (`detokenized = ''.join(pieces).replace('▁', ' ')`) --> `"Hello World."` without ambiguity and without having to save the original string seperately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
If I understand it correcly, it's to distinguish between real words (for example "_je" in 'je mange'=>'i am eating') from subwords (for example "je" in 'jeudi'=>'thursday') ?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. To be precise it's about knowing which split is a split on a whitespace and which split is a subword/punctuation split. I think in your example both might have a "▁" before them though since both have a real whitespace before them. Subtokens like the "udi" would not one before them. I don't know exactly how the tokens are used to build the vocabulary though, so how they are escaped and what goes into the actual vocubulary is different question.